# Excel Pivot Reports & Graphs - Issues with tracking data

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I exported my data from a sharepoint list into a pivot table in excel and have some issues getting my desired statistics from my table.

Currently my table consisting of a team name, and then their workload for various months each year - Displaying Hot, Within Tolerance or Cold - depending on how much actual work came in that month.

I have columns for "January Demand Project" and "January Demand Baseline", both of which have 3 choices you can select (Hot, Within Tolerance and Cold)

So when I try and create a pivot chart it only actually counts the number of "colds" or "hots" in each column. So basically a graph just displays:

```
Team 1 - January Demand Project = 1
```

Hopefully the above is clear, now then - I wish to display the table to show me if an area is "Hot" then the graph will show me a longer line than if it were cold - I could then compare the Project and Baseline graph lines side-by-side.

How is this possible? I know I can't make my vertical axis display text (as it's numeric only) will I need to change my approach and fields on my base list? Any ideas are welcome thanks.

This is how the table looks:

```
+------------------+----------------------------------+---------------------------------+

| Team Name        | January Demand Project           | January Demand Baseline         |

+------------------+----------------------------------+---------------------------------+

| Team 1           | COLD                             | HOT                             |

+------------------+----------------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to do it with a regular table, but that would require more maintenance.

With a Pivot Table, you can use Icon Sets from Conditional Formatting to accomplish the same goal but without the text. You can make Red be Cold, Yellow be Within Tolerance, and Green, Hot.